# Uploading files using js fileReader results in corrupted files

Tags: javascript, php, filereader, fileapi

I am trying to upload a file using js file reader and AJAX to my server.

I used [FileAPI](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/) and [fileReader](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#APIASynch) to read the file and convert it to string and then send it to the server via an AJAX request. 
Here is my client side js code :

```
function upload() {
    var file = document.getElementById('periodExcel').files[0];
    if (file) {
        console.log(file);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file, file.type);
        console.log(reader);
        reader.onload = uploadAndRun;
    }
}
function uploadAndRun(event) {
    console.log(event);
    var result = event.target.result;
    $('#js').html(result);
    var fileName = document.getElementById('periodExcel').files[0].name; //Should be 'picture.jpg'

    $.post('./upload.php', {data: result, name: fileName}, function(result2){
        $('#php').html(result2);
    });
}
```

Here is the upload php script:

```
file_put_contents('upload/' . $_POST['name'], $_POST['data']);
```

it just write the file using php `file_put_contents` function.

My problem is that the uploaded file is corrupted and has a different size than the original file (it is larger).

I tried to use php `file_get_contents` function to read the same file and write it again using `file_put_contents` and the result file was fine and same as the original one.

I then tried to compare the two strings (the one that comes from the *file reader* and the one that comes from *file_get_contents* ) and compares the two strings using `strcmp`, that gives me that the string that come from the `fileReader` is larger than the one comes from `file_get_contents`.

So, what is the problem with my code and how to use the FileReader to upload file in this way while using `readAsText` function.

Comment: You should use the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) api to ensure the `enctype` is set correctly when uploading files

Comment: I tried to use it but it is not get filled (append not working), and an error occur that prevent submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong collection in PHP. To access uploaded file stream use `$_FILES`. 
See here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php
and here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

In short, PHP runtime takes care of reading the upload stream from the HTTP request, stores it locally in a temp folder and exposes the above map for you to access the temp file and possibly move it to another location (or do whatever else you need to do with it).

Comment: The problem is I want to do that using AJAX and FileReader. Converting files to strings is not a wrong way, and it should work correctly. I think the problem here is that i have to remove some parts of the result string but i don't know what to remove.

Comment: Or do you mean that although i am using this method the file should be available in $_file not in $_post ?

Comment: Converting file to string will obviously only work with text files and need to take into account the charset encoding - has to be the same on the client/browser and the server. I would personally never go down this route - there are plenty of libraries that do "proper" file upload via AJAX, so converting files to strings in order to upload them is really a hack.